# facebook Request not working

Tags: android, facebook-fql, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-requests

I'm making a request to Facebook api in android with SDK 3.0.1 and I'm running it with executeAndWait() but the request doesn't work (in debug it jumps directly to next row, not even a millisecond..) and the callback is not called. Can you help me with a fix?

I'm making a request to get the user's rsvp_status of a list of events collected in `eventCollection.getAroundMeEventList()`. The request is correct (I tried it in open graph).

I never get inside the callback, so even if inside there an error I don't care about it, I want to know how to make this request work.

here's my code:

**fql string request:**

```
String rsvpRequest = "{";

            for (EventData event : eventCollection.getAroundMeEventList()) {
                rsvpRequest += "\""
                        + event.event_ID
                        + "\":"
                        + "\"SELECT rsvp_status FROM event_member where eid = "
                        + event.event_ID + "  and uid = me()\",";
            }
            rsvpRequest += "}";

            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("q", rsvpRequest);
```

facebook **Request.Callback:**

```
            Callback callback = new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObject = response.getGraphObject()
                                .getInnerJSONObject();
                        JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        jArray = jArray.getJSONArray(0);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String ID = jObject.getString("name");
                            JSONArray jj = jsonObject
                                    .getJSONArray("fql_result_set");
                            if (jj.length() == 0) {
                                eventCollection.getAroundMeEventByID(ID).status_attending = "Not Invited";
                            } else {
                                jObject = jj.getJSONObject(0);
                                eventCollection.getAroundMeEventByID(ID).status_attending = jObject
                                        .getString("rsvp_status");
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            };
```

facebook **Request**:

```
            Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "fql", bundle,
                    HttpMethod.GET, callback);
            request.executeAndWait();
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to call this is the below:

```
Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "fql", bundle,
                HttpMethod.GET);
Response response = request.executeAnWait();
```

Hope this helps